# Want records with count and duplicate values in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to get records with duplicated values and their count from them as shown below.

I am trying following query but it shows wrong count. Please suggest me.

The query that I used:

```
SELECT  msisdn, waiver_reason, COUNT(msisdn) AS cnt
FROM    ECONSOLE_NEW 
WHERE   msisdn 
IN
( 
    SELECT  [CUSTOMER CELL NUMBER]
    FROM    SOFTCLOSURE
    INTERSECT
    SELECT  msisdn
    FROM    ECONSOLE_NEW
    GROUP   BY msisdn  
    HAVING  COUNT(msisdn) > 1
)
GROUP   BY msisdn, waiver_reason 
ORDER   BY msisdn
```

Result I get:

```
msisdn waiver_reason cnt
------------------------
111    DD            1
111    VD            1
222    LP            1
222    VD            1
333    DDW           1
333    GG            1 
333    GQ            1
```

**Result I want** ==>

```
msisdn  waiver_reason  cnt 
---------------------------
111     DD             2
111     VD             2
222     LP             2
222     VD             2
333     DDW            3
333     GG             3
333     GQ             3
```

Comment: Seeing the results is helpful, are you able to share the underlying data?

Comment: it's working fine may be because of Intersect

Comment: could you please stop rolling back usefull edits

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There seems to be exactly 1 record for each `msisdn, waiver_reason` pair. You seem to want the count per `msisdn` and also, at the same time, return all `msisdn, waiver_reason` pairs.

If this is the case, then you can use window version of [**`COUNT`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175997.aspx) to get the expected result:

```
select msisdn, waiver_reason, 
       count(msisdn) over (partition by msisdn) as cnt 
from ECONSOLE_NEW 
where msisdn in 
( 
   select [CUSTOMER CELL NUMBER] from SOFTCLOSURE 
   intersect 
   select msisdn 
   from ECONSOLE_NEW 
   GROUP BY msisdn
   having COUNT(msisdn)>1 
) 
order by msisdn
```

Comment: @Steve Glad I was able to help. Please mark this, or any other, as accepted if it helped you solve your problem.

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri `SUM` with `OVER` clause is available from SQL Server 2005. The `ORDER BY` clause was added with SQL Server 2012, but I'm not using this version here.

Answer (score 1):

`cnt` column is related to `msisdn` column.

Try following query:

```
SELECT  msisdn,
        waiver_reason,
        (
            SELECT  SUM(cnt)
            FROM    ECONSOLE_NEW
            WHERE   msisdn = e.msisdn
        )   AS cnt
FROM    ECONSOLE_NEW AS e

WHERE   msisdn IN
        ( 
            SELECT  [CUSTOMER CELL NUMBER]
            FROM    SOFTCLOSURE
            INTERSECT
            SELECT  msisdn
            FROM    ECONSOLE_NEW
            GROUP   BY msisdn  
            HAVING  COUNT(msisdn) > 1
        )
GROUP   BY msisdn, waiver_reason 
ORDER   BY msisdn
```

Answer (score 1):

For performing count like this, you can use **group by** in end and then **having** clause as condition on count, like:

```
SELECT COLUMN_X, COUNT(COLUMN_X) 
FROM YOUR_TABLE 
GROUP BY COLUMN_X 
HAVING COUNT(COLUMN_X) > n;
```

It will return tuples with **column_x** value which is repeated more than **n** times in table.